# Rest Kit core data over writing master data during GET store of entity calls

Tags: ipad, core-data, restkit-0.20

I have an entity called Currency and Another entity called Order which has a relationship of one to one with Currency. The currency is mapped with an identification attribute code like this:

```
l_mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"code"];
```

Now when Order call is successful the currency relationship in the Order with same code say USD over writes the one in the Currency table. How can i avoid this? is there a way to just reference it and not create/overwrite the data in Currency table. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is a cut down version of the JSON and model classes.

```
@class Order;

@interface Currency : NSManagedObject

@property  (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber * version;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Order *billCurrencyInv;

@end
RKEntityMapping* Mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Currency" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

Mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"code" ];
[Mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"code": @"code",
    @"version": @"version",
    @"name": @"name"

}];

{
 "List": [
    {
     "code": "GBP",
     "version": 1,
     "name": "Pound"
    },
    {
     "code": "USD",
     "version": 1,
     "name": "US Dollars"
    }
 ],
 "totalCount": 2
}

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Currency;

@interface Order : NSManagedObject

@property  (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber * version;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * createdBy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Currency * billCurrency;

@end
RKEntityMapping* orderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

orderMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"type" ];
[orderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"type": @"type",
    @"createdBy": @"createdBy",
    @"version": @"version"

}];

[orderMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"billCurrency"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"billCurrency"
                                                                             withMapping:Mapping]];



{
 "List": [
    {
     "type": "Order”,
     "createdBy": "Me",
     "version": 1,
     "billCurrency": {
       "code": "GBP",
       "name": "British Pound"
     },
],
}
```

What happens is that the currency with GBP name as "Pound" is overwritten as "British - Pound". Which i dont want. I would like know if there is a way to let rest kit know that it has to reference the currency object of GBP and not create or overwrite it when making a core data object of order. I have tried will all types of relationships(order - currency) ie one-to-one, many-to-one. But to no use. if i set bill currency to transient it just does not have any data in Order which i guess is the right thing to happen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more details about your model, classes and mappings. It sounds like you aren't giving RestKit enough information to uniquely identify everything (at all times)...

Comment: Do you mean i have to give all the attributes of Currency in the identificationAttributes? . code is the only unique member and the JSON for order consists only a few attributes of currency, it is more like a reference to the master data i.e currency. But since Order is an entity when i do GET request it checks the code and updates these values on the existing master data. I would like to reference it rather than updating it. Cheers

Comment: No, I mean you need to add more details to your question because there isn't enough there for me to work out what the problem is - I need to see the model, the JSON and how you're trying to map them together...

Comment: @wain sorry, can't upload it. But i am adding the currency mapping as relationship mapping with addPropertyMapping. Both calls work fine own their own. is there no way to tell rest kit to have a reference to the actual currency object rather than create a new one and over write it. Sorry again for not being able to give you enough info. Cheers

Comment: Can you not global find and replace to show the code with different names? The identification attributes is the way of finding existing items to update instead of creating new instances...